# Installer error: Process Must Exit 1001

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

Does anybody know where this error message is derived from:

> "process must exit before requested information" 1001

I am getting this error when my client is running my setup program (the Setup Project you get with Visual Studio 2010), my program as a result, never installs. I suspect it is from using this code in my custom installer action:

> System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

Can anyone confirm or deny - and can anyone tell me what it actually means?

---

EDIT - code used to invoke process.

```
//Invoke the process.
Process Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
Process.WaitForExit(Timeout);

//Finish.
int ExitCode = Process.ExitCode;
Process.Close();
return ExitCode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at [Examine Running process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163900.aspx) the only functions which throw `System.InvalidOperationException` with information `process must exit before requested information` are `ExitCode` and `ExitTime` so you might have used these function of `Process` class to find the information of running process and used any of the two functions in wrong way.
More probably you have this code,

```
Process p = ... Your way to find a process;//
p.Kill();
int exitCode = p.ExitCode; // Or you have ExitTime used
```

Please use `WaitForExit` or `HasExited` before accessing the `ExitCode` or `ExitTime` function something like,

```
Process p = ... Your way to find a process;//
p.Kill();
while(!p.HasExited)
{ 
    p.WaitForExit(60000); //Wait for one minute 
}
int exitCode = p.ExitCode; // Or you have ExitTime used
```

**EDIT** In [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) it is also clearly mentioned with section heading **Note** that,

> The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill
>   method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit,
>   or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has
>   exited.

**EDIT** After looking at your code do this,

```
Process Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
while(!Process.HasExited)
   Process.WaitForExit(Timeout);

//Finish.
int ExitCode = Process.ExitCode;
//Process.Close(); NO NEED AS PROCESS IS ALREADY EXITED
return ExitCode;
```

Comment: Yes - I do have code similar to this - the timeout was about 10 seconds and then I do a Process.Close() - so I think perhaps the process is being closed before it's actually finished which would make some sort of sense - so maybe increase the timeout....

Comment: @Vidar can you tell me why you have started a new process while installation

Comment: Oh it's just issuing a command to register a dll inside ESRI custom registry - this will mean nothing to you if you don't work with ESRI (GIS software).  The dll's go to make up custom buttons and functionality into a piece of software called ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks for helping @dbw - I have included your code and will try to get the client to install it - hopefully it will work (fingers crossed).